# Explicit formula for this distance between positive semi-definite matrices?

Tags: pr.probability, linear-algebra, matrices, optimal-transportation

Let $A$ and $B$ in $\mathbb{R}^{d\times d}$ be positive semi-definite (psd) matrices and let $d\tau$ be the uniform probability distribution on the unit sphere $\mathbb{S}^{d-1}$ in $\mathbb{R}^d$. I am interested in the quantity
$$
S(A,B)^2 := \int_{\mathbb{S}^{d-1}} (\Vert \theta\Vert_A - \Vert \theta\Vert_B)^2 d\tau(\theta)
$$
where $\Vert \theta \Vert_A = \sqrt{\theta^\top A\theta}$ is the Mahalanobis (semi)-norm on $\mathbb{R}^d$. Is it possible to give a simpler expression for this quantity? Or at least non-trivial lower bounds?

*Where this comes from:* A well known distance between two psd matrices $A$ and $B$ is the Bures-Wasserstein distance given by 
$$
D(A,B)^2 := \mathop{tr}{A} + \mathop{tr}{B} - 2 \mathop{tr}{(A^{1/2}BA^{1/2})^{1/2}}.
$$
It equals to the $2$-Wasserstein distance between the Gaussian distributions $\mathcal{N}(0,A)$ and $\mathcal{N}(0,B)$ (see, e.g.~[Bhatia et al.](https://arxiv.org/abs/1712.01504)). Here, I am interested by the "sliced" or "Radon transform" version of this distance, obtained by averaging the squared-distance over all $1$ dimensional projections of the Gaussians (which, for a projection direction $\theta \in \mathbb{S}^{d-1}$, are Gaussians of variance $\theta^\top A\theta$ and $\theta^\top B\theta$). The expression above indeed satisfies
$$
S(A,B)^2 = \int_{\mathbb{S}^{d-1}}D(\theta^\top A \theta, \theta^\top B  \theta)^2 d\tau(\theta).
$$

Comment: Your problem can be reduced to that of computing the quantity $z(A,B) := \mathbb E_{\theta \sim \tau}[\|\theta\|_A\|\theta\|_B]$. This is because the other terms have trivial formulae, since they are expectations of quadratic forms of a random vector whose covariance matrix you know explicitly. I don't think you can compute $z(A,B)$ in closed-form for general $A$ and $B$. You can definitely obtain  (possibly crude!) lower and upper bounds for $z(A,B)$ in terms of the eigenvalues of $A$ and $B$.